# Need help to debug json response

Tags: php, json

I am trying to sent response in that form

```json
{"files":[{"webViewLink":""},{"webViewLink":""}]}
```

But I'm getting response like that

```json
{"files":[{"webViewLink":"""}]}{"files":[{"webViewLink":"""}]}
```

Here is my PHP code:

```php
<?php

    $idtemp = extractfiles($fol_id, $email);
    foreach ($idtemp['items'] as $val) {
        $id = $val['id'];
        $val = array(
            "webViewLink" =>  'https://drive.google.com/file/d/'.$val['id'].'/view?usp=drivesdk"'
            );
        $enc = json_encode($val);
        $val = '{"files":['.$enc.']}';
        echo($val);
```

Please help me to fix code i need response in that way

```json
{"files":[{"webViewLink":""},{"webViewLink":""}]}
```

Comment: Use `json_encode` to make the JSON, dont append it yourself

Comment: can you answer this please, i tried but it return same thing.

Comment: Could you add an example input? An [mre] would be very useful for us to help you. Consider reading [ask].

Comment: Also, your current code is missing a closing `}` for the `foreach`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should no do `$val = '{"files":['.$enc.']}';`

Use `json_encode` to make json, don't do it manual

---

1. Create an object with desired keys outside the loop
2. Push anything to the desired array
3. Convert to json

```php
<?php

    $idtemp = extractfiles($fol_id, $email);
    $json = (object) [
        "files" => []
    ];
    foreach ($idtemp['items'] as $val) {
        $json->files[] = (object) [
            "webViewLink" => 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/'.$val['id'].'/view?usp=drivesdk"'
        ];
    }
    $json = json_encode($json);
    echo($json);
```

---

If I use some dummy values to create an example, the output is:

```json
{
    "files": [
        {
            "webViewLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1/view?usp=drivesdk\""
        },
        {
            "webViewLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/2/view?usp=drivesdk\""
        },
        {
            "webViewLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/3/view?usp=drivesdk\""
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can test in [this online demo](https://tio.run/##bY/BCoJAEIbvPcUgggrmUt0q8wU6dxEJ3Z1czdylNT1Ez246WhA0l4F/5v/@GS113@8jLfViAUPZArNHDiHEsPJh7cMGkt00KY2qh4GrshJ540FM8ljWpajQWBAeIE5InT0XdceUS3BnbGrAbtPKg@fXS9jlgQhx8p9PGR1mpwK7Y1FfKcmRTaPNljFxL1oMcqXyCgOubmxkMcEcCChtaA5rB2v0MDqkbSOulvPFz8e@ft4c2xlrrgS6pHnTFnKpPkLfvwE)